# IntelliJ SpringBoot dependency problems

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, windows-7, spring-boot

I'm trying to follow several tutorials on how to use Spring Boot, however I keep running into issues where none of my dependencies are working properly. Below is an image displaying my problem.

[image]

I've tried making sure that I installed Maven correctly, however I imagine there is something that I'm doing wrong. I think that I have Maven in the proper Paths but, but I can't tell why it would still be providing the errors that it does. I've followed what it stated to do for Windows users, and have as follows.

[image]

Whenever I run mvn -version I am getting the following.

[image]

Can anyone help guide me in order to properly have Maven working on IntelliJ?

Comment: And what *is* the problem? Include this information directly in the question, don't make other SOers try to guess it from an image (I suspect IntelliJ marks some error using red font, but it would be a good idea to include explanation for those who never used this IDE). Did you rule out Maven itself as the culprit by running via `mvn spring-boot:run` in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA then I suggest using `Spring Initializr` which would create sample application with correctly configured maven setup is you choose `Maven Project` for `Type:`
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/03/develop-spring-boot-applications-more-productively-with-intellij-idea-14-1/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Gradle or Maven to import required dependencies? If not, follow the guides here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

If you have them setup, try to click one of the error and then click the red light bulb icon, see what it suggests you to do.